# How to find out the touch screen position

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application. In that I am using one UIImageView and I am changing the position of the UIImageView every 0.5 seconds using below code.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                 target: self
                               selector:@selector(moveImage)
                               userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
-(void) moveImage
{
   //[image1 setCenter: CGPointMake(634, 126)];
   CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);
   CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);
   CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
   img.center=squarePostion;
}
```

Now i can touch the screen. What i need to find out is my touch location and that imageview location both are correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use this 

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

 if ([touch view] == photo1) {

        //photo1 is image view give tag to it
        if( photo1.tag==3)

        {
            NSLog(@"You have been touched image view");
        }



        photo1.center = touchLocation;

    }

}
```

Comment: every time that went to else block.I written your code in touchEnded method.

Answer (score 0):

```
//it used to find the point in view
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
       NSLog(@"%f,%f",pos.x, pos.y);

}
```

Comment: When i click on my that imageview.That show the x and y values low campared to that imageview x and y values.